# PersistanceUnit annotation do not inject

Tags: java, jpa

I have a small project for education. JPA-Servlet-JSP. Now I want to use PersistanceUnit annotation:

```
public class UsersListServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        EntityManager em = null;
        try {
            em = emf.createEntityManager();

            //query for all the persons in database
            List persons = em.createQuery("select u from Users u").getResultList();
            request.setAttribute("usersList",persons);

            //Forward to the jsp page for rendering
            request.getRequestDispatcher("UsersList.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new ServletException(ex);
        } finally {
            //close the em to release any resources held up by the persistebce provider
            if(em != null) {
                em.close();
            }
        }
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    }
```

but I see NPE when try `emf.createEntityManager();`
My persistance.xml:

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="AdressBookPU">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/__adressbook</jta-data-source>
    <class>com.prokopenko.adressbook.entity.Users</class>
    <class>com.prokopenko.adressbook.entity.MobilePhone</class>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Its a maven project and persistance.xml located src/main/resources/META-INF (like in j2ee7 tutorial).
UPDATE
Tried:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "AdressBookPU")
private EntityManager em;
```

and

```
@PersistenceUnit(unitName="AdressBookPU")
private EntityManagerFactory emf;
```

Comment: Try add @PersistenceUnit(name="AdressBookPU") and don't access through EMF. Make your private var EntityManager em and use directly. Hope it helps.

Comment: I update my question. NPE...

Comment: Is `UsersListServlet` injected or just a regular class?

Comment: just a class, in question you see all listing without imports and implemented methods

Comment: and withou this annotation @WebServlet(name="UsersList", urlPatterns={"/UsersList"})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which container are you using? And have you defined in this container your jta-data-source(jdbc/__adressbook)?